# HMI - JMobile Log while connecting with EMQX server

Tags: logging, mqtt, emqx

Log Error from HMI -

```
Mar 24 23:52:42 HMI-9f7d user.notice jmlauncher: IFMqttClient: connecting...
Mar 24 23:52:42 HMI-9f7d user.notice jmlauncher: IFMqttClient: Unable to connect to XXXX:1883 (Invalid function arguments provided.).
```

[image: HMI_OS]

[image: HMI_Sys_Info]

HMI - esmart07m

I'm using Jmobile and HMI and connected in Wi-Fi with dongle. I have downloaded my HMI from Jmobile application. My software will connect only with EMQX server. In random times i got these network disconnection issue, when I go through logs of HMI I found below lines. I have no scripts or function in my software. I have also updated HMI software and System setting details.

Can anyone please tell what is the issue or reason behind this. In what scenario this error will raise. Please let me know.